# How to insert column vector at the beginning of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following two variables:

```
print('Column vector type %s and shape %s' % (type(target), target[0:X_train.shape[0]].shape))
print('Data frame type %s and shape %s' % (type(X_train), X_train.shape))
```

and this outputs:

```
Column vector type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and shape (87145,)
Data frame type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> and shape (87145, 11)
```

I'd like to insert the `target` column vector as first column for this frame / matrix ... how can I do that?

My ultimate goal is to be able to compute the correlation matrix of the response variable appended to the predictor variables or design matrix using the `corr` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
X_train.insert(0,'target',target) 
print (X_train)
```

For assign same length array like `DataFrame`:

```
X_train.insert(0,'target',target[:X_train.shape[0]]) 
print (X_train)
```